# Synonyms for "to be" in the context of "representing"

Tags: synonyms

I would like to state the following:

"Another simple class/type/kind of A **is** the one of B"

One possibility would be to write

"B constitutes/represents another simple class/type of A",

but this doesn't stress enough that we are dealing with another class of A and hence doesn't fit the context. This is why I would like to start the sentence with "Another simple class of A", but I am missing a good word for **is**, because I don't think that it is the correct word.

Concrete example:

"Another simple class of spanning graphs is the one of Hamilton cycles."

I do not like the repeated appearance of "of" here.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Any reason you do not want to go with A is _another case_ or _instance_ of B?

Comment: *"Hamilton Cycles is another example of a spanning graph"*

Comment: Hamilton Cycles form/comprise another subset of spanning graphs.

Comment: Why I do not really want these 3 versions is that they start with Hamilton cycles (=B) instead of spanning subgraph (=A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello this works well I would say, it's tighter and also avoids the repetition you mentioned:

> "Another simple class of A is B"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start the sentence stressing 'Another simple class', it seems to be best and clearest to stick to the verb 'be'. To write 'Hamilton cycles are another type of simple spanning graphs' is turning it round, but still clear. Your example could be simplified to 'Another simple class of the spanning graph is Hamilton cycles'. Alternatively, rephrase or explicate using all manner of tricks: 'goes by the name of' or 'is known as..' or 'is named after....', 'takes/follows a/the model developed by...'.